# SoapFault: looks like we got no XML document in+PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a problem I have no idea how to solve. I need to send xml via soap to the public server. It is returning this error, I have reviewed several times and it does not seem to be an error with xml. Can anybody help me?

```
private function send($operation, DOMDocument $xmlDoc) {              
       //versão do SOAP
        $soapver = SOAP_1_2;
       // $wsdl = 'https://nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx?WSDL';
        $wsdl = 'https://nfse.blumenau.sc.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx?WSDL'; // Felipe Rau
        $endpoint = "http://nfse.blumenau.sc.gov.br/ws/envioRPS";
        $params = array(
            'local_cert' => $this->key,
            'passphrase' => $this->passphrase,
            'connection_timeout' => 300,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'verifypeer' => false,
            'verifyhost' => false,
            'soap_version' => $soapver,
            'trace' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'location' => $endpoint                     
        );

        try {
            $this->connectionSoap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $params);         
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            throw new \Common\Exception\RuntimeException($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new $e;
        }       
       $this->signXML($xmlDoc);                 
       $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
       $params = array(
            'VersaoSchema' => 1,            
            //'MensagemXML' => trim($xmlDoc->saveXML())         
            'MensagemXML' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><PedidoEnvioRPS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://nfse.blumenau.sc.gov.br"><Cabecalho xmlns="" Versao="1"><CPFCNPJRemetente><CNPJ>02145346000103</CNPJ></CPFCNPJRemetente></Cabecalho><RPS xmlns=""><Assinatura>Hw4rqRIbF84mJ2X8Ycn4GYjjvVtuNEKDdZvKZkznvx1JliJWlfYtm7qkh319yDtZGVvQfv/3tj7/PoLlARCOcC+Z17ht+ChxUMJOtxWma2oiXIh10IfBd3scchsIg6JKwL4j9A/hvETzuFvn3IOETKsWku2FTmYnHGZiCsak0zu8uy/hAPIvmoU9W78zRCIy3xYoVJVyrta/r519pHiCzYYP/tD66jyqxzhoZxfVRpBUOjQHu9pVd8mwsbQlZdi+faCPvnWq4kNCj7xROOopZ+8yG5UKpt4e87CP4oWjMR24RiLiVKCmh/vNzHSLvuQ55J5nrksLH3vq6XmhnE0rOA==</Assinatura><ChaveRPS><InscricaoPrestador>60745</InscricaoPrestador><SerieRPS>001</SerieRPS><NumeroRPS>217</NumeroRPS></ChaveRPS><TipoRPS>RPS</TipoRPS><DataEmissao>2019-02-20</DataEmissao><StatusRPS>N</StatusRPS><TributacaoRPS>T</TributacaoRPS><ValorServicos>1</ValorServicos><ValorDeducoes>0</ValorDeducoes><CodigoServico>07498</CodigoServico><AliquotaServicos>0.05</AliquotaServicos><ISSRetido>false</ISSRetido><CPFCNPJTomador><CPF>06005738933</CPF></CPFCNPJTomador><RazaoSocialTomador>Felipe RAu</RazaoSocialTomador><EnderecoTomador><TipoLogradouro>R</TipoLogradouro><Logradouro>Rua Frederico Giewlo</Logradouro><NumeroEndereco>numero</NumeroEndereco><ComplementoEndereco>complemento</ComplementoEndereco><Bairro>bairro_do_destinatario</Bairro><Cidade>3550308</Cidade><UF>SP</UF><CEP>89040362</CEP></EnderecoTomador><EmailTomador>felipe@bonssens.com.br</EmailTomador><Discriminacao>Teste de geracao de NFS-e via sistema proprio</Discriminacao></RPS><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/> <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>S8Ljeg044AoZnrj69iIR7ib8t2U=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>i8g3iWtpSJq//qL0WuDPY0jKOKIC9jKZ+yN2bs75Ll1JeAUwVjrNf9RXq67xvu3JY7h4UWsexNUXSEW45tWHQ8bg02/sne8JyaV3v2Wu+uPkYE00bvLaiNJ/XB6nvXOGdJLkw/kAMDd46E7YaGYvNbj2gXSM8D+XkwvB2tc4NVKncJNz85jMloVhmp1H71UE/fHwNhzT4AsbiK3o0J3sRO3sngbip1xAvz3i5DXjbHYvuoj6sQDJMh8McdvNsD5w5axOQckn2LxAtPqSuczy98ffOp4v/GY0Jz08KLGN2LD9+gE7YtiPMj/rGfJJvMBRxxHxddCqsXQR/5Q3QqT9Zw==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIIHqDCCBZCgAwIBAgIIbBsZAQdaWsgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgYkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJSMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpJQ1AtQnJhc2lsMTQwMgYDVQQLEytBdXRvcmlkYWRlIENlcnRpZmljYWRvcmEgUmFpeiBCcmFzaWxlaXJhIHYyMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlBQyBTT0xVVEkxGzAZBgNVBAMTEkFDIFNPTFVUSSBNdWx0aXBsYTAeFw0xOTAxMTQxMzQwMDBaFw0yMDAxMTQxMzQwMDBaMIHdMQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjETMBEGA1UEChMKSUNQLUJyYXNpbDE0MDIGA1UECxMrQXV0b3JpZGFkZSBDZXJ0aWZpY2Fkb3JhIFJhaXogQnJhc2lsZWlyYSB2MjESMBAGA1UECxMJQUMgU09MVVRJMRswGQYDVQQLExJBQyBTT0xVVEkgTXVsdGlwbGExGjAYBgNVBAsTEUNlcnRpZmljYWRvIFBKIEExMTYwNAYDVQQDEy1RVUFMSVRZIEZBQ0NBTyBFIFNFUlZJQ09TIExUREE6MDIxNDUzNDYwMDAxMDMwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCN59D+7D+FGqtHfTXdtk3WobFfZwyvcOM5LeVXCxYYnydN5au4qmu6guaDfJoZ2PLL/7HAl4AVTwSpbSs0FJRQgAosYGQfpR4YaLr92VpDS33zDIczhwPeXo3edTB1+uycN4qZH7nd3qs03Kk6nWfJutiXYGoFVn0daQB8/qotm+rU0+I8YP4JGSJt3n7Zg5VlLcrQX0qcBd4MlLzHnMnlqzMbnOqZ8tVBqX7Mw4ZxH0oDt2WndYVp/VnjRoVYOZJXTftGqFeHGtTETNmI6pZLyxoar2nn43xo7qcs+aHlX+nZ7+r9Pe+eSq9fxLaGp14tjDUMoeYUFIpktv1Js7MJAgMBAAGjggK8MIICuDBUBggrBgEFBQcBAQRIMEYwRAYIKwYBBQUHMAKGOGh0dHA6Ly9jY2QuYWNzb2x1dGkuY29tLmJyL2xjci9hYy1zb2x1dGktbXVsdGlwbGEtdjEucDdiMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTBseltpdNAccqRqlZ0ee098W4NmTAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFDWuMRT2XtJ6T1j+NKgaZ5cKxJsHMF4GA1UdIARXMFUwUwYGYEwBAgEmMEkwRwYIKwYBBQUHAgEWO2h0dHBzOi8vY2NkLmFjc29sdXRpLmNvbS5ici9kb2NzL2RwYy1hYy1zb2x1dGktbXVsdGlwbGEucGRmMIHeBgNVHR8EgdYwgdMwPqA8oDqGOGh0dHA6Ly9jY2QuYWNzb2x1dGkuY29tLmJyL2xjci9hYy1zb2x1dGktbXVsdGlwbGEtdjEuY3JsMD+gPaA7hjlodHRwOi8vY2NkMi5hY3NvbHV0aS5jb20uYnIvbGNyL2FjLXNvbHV0aS1tdWx0aXBsYS12MS5jcmwwUKBOoEyGSmh0dHA6Ly9yZXBvc2l0b3Jpby5pY3BicmFzaWwuZ292LmJyL2xjci9BQ1NPTFVUSS9hYy1zb2x1dGktbXVsdGlwbGEtdjEuY3JsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIF4DAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwQwgaQGA1UdEQSBnDCBmYETbW1vc2VyQHRlcnJhLmNvbS5icqAUBgVgTAEDAqALEwlIT1JTVCBSQVWgGQYFYEwBAwOgEBMOMDIxNDUzNDYwMDAxMDOgOAYFYEwBAwSgLxMtMjcwNzE5NjI0ODYzNjAwMjkxNTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwoBcGBWBMAQMHoA4TDDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAMonzbAchXNWOgquQFSjHAreUcNm00Etqx50/s0j5bXppp88wpRUo5XQGNCKDe+UO4sX13sMgTxS9rdK2yhzMm1B4hE9ajnUltJ2dwLJbbY0/jtR7lksKwxF/MzRsLDb0NI0UOMI7VT4OnTgLx9b1wt6h8RZdvhKp7YZVHf17sIyeovw45bA3qJHVw8PgSkbx0Q56J79+BVwvZKrdbsdriRWdL2/lUoeG+js4GgPf2492DK2Cuex+NGOVLtS5FjKbcVpwmt65P1b3OBBLL58VrWMbdHWCNqD6Tie7iO3AWG0axWRMEsxyqbP2fDAzEQVrswwe8XPjzp39/6FTKhpn2V3mw3S+4uu13VMjZ16dEmsw21otRMm6bBYF8jyYyk1OUVfw6xzxvd454jPbMomm1Uj58tHGR7p2jgwROEh9MbhQLsnWBWjn1azvnjN1E8jR+C+3pYkh97ROXke6Bv958eUArrzaOVyETU5176W2JNlXQf6OQGoGlBfAjL5E971wk7xs7Vr3SkRTthkrPoirxeNs3qInnknqRvwHMLeM4+Xm2dbaUSXfvVAsbWpmzHYJNjA10s6IHGz0BKRMqGO+ky+WyLV+zfCp5xGUngnxCukeVDZkFKpTp3BsdP6GCuwJ4IgzsvpzuNS1dCXbXZOcaVVD89sbA2thNVmVypt0XXI=</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></PedidoEnvioRPS>'
        );



        /*$dirfile = "arquivos_clientes/02145346000103/nfse";     
        $filename = "paulista-nfse.xml";   
        $filexmlMdfe = $dirfile."/".$filename;         
        file_put_contents($filexmlMdfe, $xmlDoc->saveXML()); // Salva o xml   
        echo "aqui";
        die();*/



      //  try {

            //$this->connectionSoap->__soapCall("LoteNFeSoap", $params);                        
            $result = $this->connectionSoap->$operation($params);
            //$function = 'EnvioRPS';
            //$arguments = ['EnvioRPS' => ['xml'=>$xmlDoc->saveXML()]];

            //$result = $this->connectionSoap->__soapCall($function, $params);

            print_r($result->RetornoXML);
           /* echo($this->connectionSoap->__getLastResponse());
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo($this->connectionSoap->__getLastRequest());*/

            die();

        //} catch (SoapFault $e) {
        //     print_r($result->RetornoXML);
    //       echo PHP_EOL;
    //       echo($this->connectionSoap->__getLastResponse());
     //        echo PHP_EOL;
      //       echo($this->connectionSoap->__getLastRequest());
    //      die();
//          throw new \Common\Exception\RuntimeException($e->getMessage());
    //    } catch (Exception $e) {
     //      throw new $e;
     //   }
        return new SimpleXMLElement($result->RetornoXML);
    }
```

> Return error: "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender]
>   looks like we got no XML document in
>   C:\wamp64\www\NovoFac\nfephp\libs\NFSe\NFSeSP.class.php on line 217"